# How to set a lower width when one div is on top of the other and the bottom slides out on hover?

Tags: css, hover, width, slide

I have one div on top of another. On hover, the bottom div (the right-side gray bar) slides out and is the same width as the top div: http://d.pr/OB6N. I'm trying to create a grid of images with slide-outs. Is there a way to set the width to be as much as is shown in the image? Because right now, when I inspect the element, the width is the total of the top div and the slide-out div (when fully slid out).

```
 HTML:
    <div class="poster">
     <img src="example.png" />
    </div>
    <div class="bottombox"></div>

CSS:

.poster {
    float: left;
    width: 250px;
    height: 375px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: 1;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.2s;
}

.bottombox {
    float: left;
    width: 250px;
    height: 375px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    left: -225px;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.2s;
}

.bottombox:hover {
    left: 0px;
}
```

Hope that makes sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So it would be much easier to help you if you created a jsfiddle to play with. That said, one approach is to make .bottombox a child of the .poster element

```
<div class="poster">
  <img src="example.png" />
  <div class="bottombox"></div>
</div>
```

then change the css of .poster to

```
width: auto
```

and change the css of .bottombox to

```
width: 100%;
position: absolute;
left: 25px;
```

and last set the hover definition to

```
left: 100%;
```

Comment: Ah, sorry. Here's the jsfiddle of what I had, hope it helps. http://jsfiddle.net/A2cPn/1/ Thanks for the suggestion, though unfortunately it didn't quite work for me. One div was on top, and the other was on bottom, vertically. But they weren't "stacked" so to speak.

Comment: Hey, that's great- thanks! Changed the z-index of .bottombox to -1, since I wanted it to be behind the actual poster, and when you hover over the poster, it slides out. Again, sweet. Thank you.

Comment: hey, can you check off this as the correct answer? :) Thanks and glad to help.

Comment: I actually didn't get your answer to work for me, but the code in the jsfiddle link you made, did the trick.